# Make jQuery popup close button appear after a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I use jQuery for my popup, and it has a close button. I want to make that close button appear after 30-60 seconds with the words `"wait 60 seconds to close this window"`. Here's the code now:

```
var shadow = $('<div id="shadowElem"></div>');
var speed = 1000;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').prepend(shadow);
});
$(window).load( function() {
    screenHeight = $(window).height();
    screenWidth = $(window).width();
    elemWidth = $('#dropElem').outerWidth(true);
    elemHeight = $('#dropElem').outerHeight(true)

    leftPosition = (screenWidth / 2) - (elemWidth / 2);
    topPosition = (screenHeight / 2) - (elemHeight / 2);

    $('#dropElem').css({
        'left' : leftPosition + 'px',
        'top' : -elemHeight + 'px'
    });
    $('#dropElem').show().animate({
        'top' : topPosition
    }, speed);

    shadow.animate({
        'opacity' : 0.7
    }, speed);

    $('#dropClose').click( function() {
        shadow.animate({
            'opacity' : 0
        }, speed);
        $('#dropElem').animate({
        'top' : -elemHeight + 'px'
    }, speed, function() {
            shadow.remove();
            $(this).remove();
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Use setTimeout() to fire something after certain time. Tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Try (I assumed that `dropClose` is the id of the close button) ...

**CSS**

```
#dropClose {
  display: none;
}
```

**In the Open the Popup code**

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#dropClose").show();
}, 30 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ndjddysw/1/) Hope this help .. Change Ids with your Ids or classes you want

you need to use setInterval() and clearInterval() after you seconds = 0  and change your button text to close

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var setIt = true;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(setIt == true){
            $('#count span').text($('#count span').text() - 1);
            if($('#count span').text() == '0'){
                $('#count').text('Close This Window');
                clearInterval(interval);
                setIt = false;
            }
        }
    },1000);
});
```